# How to join multiple rows from same table and select only the column with not NULL values + add an alias to the column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a SQL Query to join multiple rows of the same table and select the relevant columns (only NOT NULL columns).
Here's what you have to know about my tables:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is retrieve all products with all their attributes (named).
To illustrate, if I have 2 attributes named "attribute_1" and "attribute_2", the final result shoud look like this:

```
{
 "id" => 1,
 "attribute_1" => "The attribute value", //The attribute value can be stored in any column suffixed by "_value"
 "attribute_2" => "The attribute value"  //The attribute value can be stored in any column suffixed by "_value"
}
```

I'm working with Laravel and ATM, here's what I'm doing:

```
//First retrieve all attribute names
$attribute_names = Attribute::select('name')->pluck('name');

//Build the final select statement that will be used
foreach ($attribute_names as $attribute_name) {
     $select_array[] = DB::raw("MAX(CASE WHEN name='" . $attribute_name . "' THEN value ELSE NULL END) as " . $attribute_name);
}

//Sub query to select only the right column (the one that is not NULL)
$sub_query_select_only_not_null_columns = DB::table('attributes')
            ->leftJoin('product_attribute_values', 'product_attribute_values.attribute_id', 'attributes.id')
            ->select(
                DB::raw('CASE 
                        WHEN text_value IS NOT NULL THEN text_value
                        WHEN boolean_value IS NOT NULL THEN boolean_value
                        WHEN integer_value IS NOT NULL THEN integer_value
                        WHEN float_value IS NOT NULL THEN float_value
                        WHEN datetime_value IS NOT NULL THEN datetime_value
                        WHEN date_value IS NOT NULL THEN date_value
                        WHEN json_value IS NOT NULL THEN json_value
                        END AS value
                    '),
                'attributes.name',
                'product_attribute_values.product_id as product_id'
            );

//Final query
Products::leftJoin('products', 'product_flat.product_id', '=', 'products.id') //Ignore this join 
            ->leftJoinSub($sub_query_select_only_not_null_columns, 'mysubquery', function ($join) {
                $join->on('products.id', '=', 'mysubquery.product_id');
            })->select($select_array)->groupBy('products.id')
```

This query is working but there are some problems:

- I have to query all attribute names first (not really a problem for me but still)
- If I don't filter in the main query with some products ids ->whereIn('products.id',[1,2,3,4,5,6]) then it looks like the subquery is retrieving all the attribute values for all products and the query take a while. Even if I limit the main query, the subquery will fetch all product_attribute_values of all products.

So here are my questions:

- Is there a way to achieve all this with a single query ?
- Should I use an SQL View instead ?
- If I want to stick with my query, what should I do to only fetch the product_attribute_values that related to the products that will be present in the result ?
- For that SQL Schema, what is the best way to do what I want ?

The problem is a bit complex to explain/understand. I can provide some more informations if you need.
PS: I didn't provide the SQL because the query is a bit long, but I can share it.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Feels like you can find a workaround using group_concat or union, but most importantly if there's going to be so many null values, that might not be a good design. Normalisation should be prioritised if possible. If I had the option, I would change the attr_values table to have a `type` field and a `value` field. So for instance for float values `type` will be `float` and `value` will have its value, and so on.  No more needing to worry about excluding null values. Then again this comes down to preference and possibility.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! In fact the design has been done this way in Bagisto (E-commerce PHP module) and I can't really modify the models definition since we use it in my company for other projects... Thanks for your advice !

Comment: Mind sharing a sample dataset?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a M:N relationship between `Product` and `Attribute` using `ProductAttributeValue` as a pivot model

```php
# Product model

public function attributes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class, 'product_attribute_values', 'product_id', 'attribute_id')
                ->withPivot('text_value', 'boolean_value', ..., 'json_value')
                ->using(ProductAttributeValue::class);
}
```

2. Make an accessorfor the value in `ProductAttributeValue` model

```
# ProductAttributeValue model

public function getValueAttribute()
{
    return $this->text_value
        ?? $this->boolean_value
        ?? ...
        ?? $this->json_value;
}
```

3. Query

```
$product = Product::with('attributes')->find(1);
```

4. Format your result

```
$result = json_encode(
    array_merge(
        ['id' => $product->id],
        $product->attributes
                ->mapWithKeys(fn($attribute) => [$attribute->name => $attribute->pivot->value])
                ->toArray()
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I tried your solution and I have all the data in my query results. Hower my problem remains unsolved, because the solution you provided uses collection for example to map the attributes with their names and what I need is a pure SQL solution. Because the query is used in a DataGrid, so I can't play with the query results. Every attributes has to be joined and named in the SQL query.

Comment: There are no easy ways to do what you want. However, if you don't care about the alias part you could just use `group_concat`